# ftp upload is too big

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, network-programming, vsto

I've written a function in C# to upload a file when copying to a file share does not work.  I'm noticing that any uploaded files are about 1.5-2x the size of the original and are invalid files.  Here is the code:

```
public bool save_FTPUpload(FileInfo fi_attachment)
{
    bool fileSaved = false;
    string filename = fi_attachment.Name;

    while (!fileSaved)
    {
        string file_ftpURI = string.Format("{0}/{1}", ftpURI, filename);
        FtpWebRequest file_exist_request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(file_ftpURI);
        file_exist_request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftp_user, ftp_pass);
        file_exist_request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;
        try
        {
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)file_exist_request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ex.Response;
            if (response.StatusCode ==
                FtpStatusCode.ActionNotTakenFileUnavailable)
            {
                FtpWebRequest upload_request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(file_ftpURI);
                upload_request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftp_user, ftp_pass);

                upload_request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                upload_request.UsePassive = true;
                upload_request.UseBinary = true;
                upload_request.KeepAlive = false;

                StreamReader attachment = new StreamReader(fi_attachment.FullName);
                byte[] attachmentData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(attachment.ReadToEnd());
                upload_request.ContentLength = attachmentData.Length;

                //Stream upload_request_stream = upload_request.GetRequestStream();
                using (Stream upload_request_stream = upload_request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    upload_request_stream.Write(attachmentData, 0, attachmentData.Length);
                    upload_request_stream.Close();
                }
                FtpWebResponse upload_response = (FtpWebResponse)upload_request.GetResponse();

                fileSaved = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return fileSaved;
}
```

Any help in figuring this out would be great.

Comment: You're doing a _lot_ in that `catch` block.  Why?  What error are you handling and how are you trying to handle it?  By... uploading a file?

Comment: @David - The catch block is to check for a valid FTP connection.  Picked it up someplace (probably here on SO)

Comment: That's definitely something you'll want to fix, then.  I haven't discovered the root cause of the problem you're reporting, but using a `try/catch` for logic flow is _never_ a good idea.

Comment: Is attachment always a test file, or is it sometimes a binary?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Attachment is the actual file, usually binary.

Comment: @David - actually, the try/catch was gleaned from a sample on how to see if a file already existed on the FTP server.  I know it's not the best method, but catching that exception was the best solution I was able to find

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to copy the content of the file in binary mode, like this:

```
var response = (FtpWebResponse)ex.Response;
if (response.StatusCode == FtpStatusCode.ActionNotTakenFileUnavailable) {
    FtpWebRequest upload_request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(file_ftpURI);
    upload_request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftp_user, ftp_pass);
    upload_request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    upload_request.UsePassive = true;
    upload_request.UseBinary = true;
    upload_request.KeepAlive = false;
    var attachment = File.Open(fi_attachment.FullName, FileMode.Open);
    using (Stream upload_request_stream = upload_request.GetRequestStream()) {
        attachment.CopyTo(upload_request_stream);
        upload_request_stream.Close();
    }
    var upload_response = (FtpWebResponse)upload_request.GetResponse();
    fileSaved = true;
}
```

Your current program reads it as a very long string in UTF-8 encoding, which probably accounts for the change in file size.

Comment: +1. Solved my problem with corrupted files too. I was using the MSDN sample, which does the UTF-8-Encoding without further explanation. It should be noted that the "CopyTo"-Method is .NET 4.0 and up only. (Stumped me for a minute because my project defaulted to .NET 3.5)

Answer (score 2):

Why all this dance decoding a file then re-encoding it? You've got two streams right? You want the same file you have on disk to exist on the server? [`Stream.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx) would be considerably less error prone.

You could replace

```
                StreamReader attachment = new StreamReader(fi_attachment.FullName);
                byte[] attachmentData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(attachment.ReadToEnd());
                upload_request.ContentLength = attachmentData.Length;

                //Stream upload_request_stream = upload_request.GetRequestStream();
                using (Stream upload_request_stream = upload_request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    upload_request_stream.Write(attachmentData, 0, attachmentData.Length);
                    upload_request_stream.Close();
                }
```

with (off the top of my head)

```
using (var fs = File.OpenRead(fi_attachment.FullName))
using (Stream upload_request_stream = upload_request.GetRequestStream())
{
    fs.CopyTo(upload_request_stream);
}
```