# Uploading file to ftp adds unwanted (garbage) characters at the end of that file

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest

What i try to do is saving XML document to stream, modifying it and saving a file on ftp. But after all these steps at the end of the file i get trash characters like 㼼浸⁬敶獲潩㵮ㄢ... Where is the problem?

```
XmlDocument xmlD = (XmlDocument)xmlDocument.Clone();
byte[] fileContents = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(xmlD.OuterXml);
//ftpWReqUpload - FtpWebRequest to upload file
Stream requestStream = ftpWReqUpload.GetRequestStream();
xmlD.Save(requestStream);
ftpWReqUpload.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;
requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
requestStream.Close();
```

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8495303/335858), it demonstrates the technique using a file stream as the source, but I'm sure that it can be adopted for your purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, you're uploading the document twice. First you do `xmlD.Save()` to the stream which will save your document in its original encoding, then you write a byte array that you got from the same document using the system default encoding. I suspect that if you just do something like;

```
XmlDocument xmlD = xmlDocument as XmlDocument;
Stream requestStream = ftpWReqUpload.GetRequestStream();
xmlD.Save(requestStream);
requestStream.Close();
```

it will work.

Edit: I see @dasblinkenlight added a link to some working code to the comments to the question, you may want to take a look at that to get an idea how to handle the response.

Answer (score 0):

The code I'm using to upload a file through FTP is approximately the same, but it does not have the line

```
ftpWReqUpload.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.contentlength%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) says you shouldn't use it in your code.  Try without it.