# Uploading files to FTP are corrupted once in destination

Tags: c#, winforms, ftpwebrequest

I'm creating a simple drag-file-and-upload-automatically-to-ftp windows application

[image]

and I'm using the [MSDN code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715.aspx) to upload the file to the FTP.

The code is pretty straight forward:

```
// Get the object used to communicate with the server.
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(String.Format("{0}{1}", FTP_PATH, filenameToUpload));
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

// Options
request.UseBinary = true;
request.UsePassive = false;

// FTP Credentials
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FTP_USR, FTP_PWD);

// Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(fileToUpload.FullName);
byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
sourceStream.Close();
request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
requestStream.Close();

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
writeOutput("Upload File Complete!");
writeOutput("Status: " + response.StatusDescription);

response.Close();
```

and **it does** get uploaded to the FTP

[image]

**Problem is** when I see the file on a browser, or simply download and try to see it on desktop I get:

[image]

I already used `request.UseBinary = false;` and `request.UsePassive = false;` but it does not seam to do any kind of good whatsoever.

**What I have found out** was that, the original file has 122Kb lenght and in the FTP (and after downloading), it has 219Kb...

> What am I doing wrong?

By the way, the `uploadFileToFTP()` method is running inside a `BackgroundWorker`, but I don't really thing that makes any difference...

Comment: Binary data and UTF-8 doesn't mix well.

Comment: @dtb using `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());` gets the same behavior...

Comment: Sigh. **Binary** data and **character** data are two different things. Yes, you can encode characters to bytes, but you can not blindly decode bytes that do not encode characters.

Comment: Instead of StreamReader, you should probably try [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx).

Comment: found out a near duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495064/ftp-upload-is-too-big

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You shouldn't use a StreamReader but only a Stream to read binary files.

Streamreader is designed to read text files only.

Try with this :

```
private static void up(string sourceFile, string targetFile)
{            
    try
    {
        string ftpServerIP = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftpIP"];
        string ftpUserID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftpUser"];
        string ftpPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftpPass"];
        ////string ftpURI = "";
        string filename = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "//" + targetFile; 
        FtpWebRequest ftpReq = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(filename);
        ftpReq.UseBinary = true;
        ftpReq.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        ftpReq.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);

        byte[] b = File.ReadAllBytes(sourceFile);

        ftpReq.ContentLength = b.Length;
        using (Stream s = ftpReq.GetRequestStream())
        {
            s.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
        }

        FtpWebResponse ftpResp = (FtpWebResponse)ftpReq.GetResponse();

        if (ftpResp != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ftpResp.StatusDescription);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2212907 : if it helped you, upvote the answer so that it helps others ;)

Comment: Thank you. This was my problem too.

Answer (score 3):

The problems are caused by your code decoding the binary data to character data and back to binary data. Don't do this.

---

Use the [UploadFile Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs.aspx) of the [WebClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx):

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FTP_USR, FTP_PWD);
    client.UploadFile(FTP_PATH + filenameToUpload, filenameToUpload);
}
```

Comment: That class is bad. Throws exceptions like hell. Not been able to perform upload.

Comment: You saved my life bro, why people using that annoying code, this one is the best +1