# Uploading files to ftp folder having special characters in name

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I am trying to upload a file on FTP folder, but getting the following error.

> The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g.,
>   file not found, no access)

I am using the following sample to test this:

```
    // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
    string path = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("ftp://host:port//01-03-2017/John, Doe S. M.D/file.wav");
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(path);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

    // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");

    // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
    StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(@"localpath\example.wav");
    byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
    sourceStream.Close();
    request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

    response.Close();
```

- I am able to upload files on the parent folder `01-03-2017` but not in the target folder `ROLLINS, SETH S. M.D` which clearly has special characters in it.
- I am able to upload files using FileZilla
- I have tried to `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` but that did n't help

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: The problem is with the url: use "//" after every folder name instead of "/" @Ankit

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this:

```
string path = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("ftp://96.31.95.118:2121//01-03-2017//ROLLINS, SETH S. M.D//30542_3117.wav");
```

or You can form a Uri using the following code and pass it webrequest.

```
var path = new Uri("ftp://96.31.95.118:2121//01-03-2017//ROLLINS, SETH S. M.D//30542_3117.wav");
```

Comment: This will get you `ftp%3a%2f%2f96.31.95.118%3a2121%2f%2f01-03-2017%2f%2fROLLINS%2c+SETH+S.+M.D%2f%2f30542_3117.wav`. That does not look like a correct way (even if it works by chance).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, Yes,  this solution is incorrect. My comment is misplaced and should have been after Prabhu's comment on the question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to encode the spaces (and maybe commas) in the URL path, like:

```
string path =
    "ftp://host:port/01-03-2017/" +
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode("John, Doe S. M.D") + "/file.wav";
```

Effectively, you get:

```
ftp://host:port/01-03-2017/John%2c+Doe+S.+M.D/file.wav
```

Answer (score 2):

The code works on a C# console application but did not work in Web Api Action. I could not manage to find the reason.

So I have used a free library for the same.

Posting the sample code from one of the examples available [here](https://github.com/hgupta9/FluentFTP/blob/master/FluentFTP.Examples/OpenWrite.cs):

So i have used [FluentFtp](https://github.com/hgupta9/FluentFTP) libary available through [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentFTP).

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using FluentFTP;

namespace Examples {
    public class OpenWriteExample {
        public static void OpenWrite() {
            using (FtpClient conn = new FtpClient()) {
                conn.Host = "localhost";
                conn.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ftptest", "ftptest");

                using (Stream ostream = conn.OpenWrite("01-03-2017/John, Doe S. M.D/file.wav")) {
                    try {
                        // istream.Position is incremented accordingly to the writes you perform
                    }
                    finally {
                        ostream.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Again, if the file is a binary file, [StreamReader should not be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10330779/3615478) as explained here.